# Writing on existing Excel file in Go

Tags: go

There's any way to write on an existing Excel file in Go?, i've tried with some libraries that are basically to create the excel file from blank but i need to write on an existing file.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Using the excel package @Marc recommended, i got this error:

```
panic: Ocurrió una excepción.

goroutine 16 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x4afb40, 0xc082000440)
    c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0x11f
github.com/mattn/go-ole/oleutil.MustCallMethod(0x1cf688, 0x4eb870, 0x4, 0x2e3e38, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc082007080)
    C:/Go/path/src/github.com/mattn/go-ole/oleutil/oleutil.go:58 +0xdd
github.com/nivrrex/excel.(*Excel).Open(0x2e3f08, 0x4f3d70, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/path/src/github.com/nivrrex/excel/excel.go:65 +0x582
main.main()
    C:/Desarrollo/Projects/excel_writer_go/excel_writer.go:12 +0xa0

goroutine 19 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.park(0x414d40, 0x576c00, 0x575649)
    c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1369 +0xac
runtime.parkunlock(0x576c00, 0x575649)
    c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1385 +0x42
runfinq()
    c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2644 +0xdd
runtime.goexit()
    c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
exit status 2
[Finished in 4.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: go build C:\Desarrollo\Projects\excel_writer_go\excel_writer.go & go run C:\Desarrollo\Projects\excel_writer_go\excel_writer.go]
[dir: C:\Desarrollo\Projects\excel_writer_go]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Go\bin]
```

**CODE**
This is the code i tried to use.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/nivrrex/excel"
)

func main() {

    e := &excel.Excel{Visible: false, Readonly: false, Saved: true}
    filePath := "test.xlsx"
    e.Open(filePath)

    //Print
    fmt.Println(e.Cells(1, 1))
    e.Sheet(1)
    e.CellsWrite("Hello", 2, 2)
    e.Save()
    e.Close()

}
```

Comment: what about a CSV file ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this [package](https://github.com/nivrrex/excel), which is built on top of the ole bindings for go that can be found [here](https://github.com/mattn/go-ole/)

The [CellsWrite](https://github.com/nivrrex/excel/blob/master/excel.go#L171) function should do what you want:

```
func (this *Excel) CellsWrite(value string, row int, column int) (err error)
```

Comment: Take a look at the update please, i got that error using this package.

Answer (score 0):

Excelize is a library written in pure Go and providing a set of functions that allow you to write to and read from XLSX files.

https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize